# linked list insert and printing C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

So i am trying to use double pointers to create insert function and then print the linked list.

I managed to do it with single pointers but this double pointer is driving me insane.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
   string name;
   int ID;
   int marks[10];
   Node *next;
};

void printOptions() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1.Insert New Node" << endl;
    cout << "2.Print List" << endl;
    cout << "3.Exit" << endl;
}

void insertAtBack(string inputName, Node **headref) {
    Node **currentNodeRef;
    currentNodeRef = headref;

        while ((*currentNodeRef)->next != NULL) {
             (*currentNodeRef) = (*currentNodeRef)->next;
    }
    (*currentNodeRef)->next = new Node();
    (*currentNodeRef)->next->name = inputName;
    (*currentNodeRef)->next->next = NULL;

 }

 void printList(Node *head) {
    Node *indexNode;
    indexNode = head;
    while (indexNode != NULL) {
        cout << (indexNode)->name << endl;
        (indexNode) = (indexNode)->next;
    }
  }

 int main() {

       cout << "This implements a linked list" << endl;

       int option;
       bool infinite = true;

       Node *head = NULL;
       string testName;

       while (infinite == true) {
         printOptions();
         std::cin >> option;


         switch (option) {

         case 1:
            cout << "Enter student name" << endl;
            std::cin >> testName;
            if (head == NULL) {
                 head = new Node();
                 head->name = testName;
            }
            else {
                 insertAtBack(testName, &head);
            }
            break;

         case 2:
             printList(head);
             break;

         case 3:
             exit(1);
             break;
         default:
             exit(1);
             break;
         }

       }
     return 0; 
    }
```

So there is no compilation error or seg fault but instead the code runs it takes in 2 values and prints them fine. when the another value is typed inserted it only prints 2 values no more.
I think the print function is good because it worked previously with single pointer but i am not 100% sure.
I think the problem is in the insert function but i am not sire where.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel and not just using `std::list` or (usually better) `std::vector`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl nice you just commented that... for absolutely no reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> void insertAtBack(string inputName, Node **headref) {
>     Node **currentNodeRef;
>     currentNodeRef = headref;
>     ...
> ```

`Node **currentNodeRef = headref;` is an error. Remember you are passing the address of a pointer. You mean to write:

```
Node *currentNodeRef = *headref;
```

And change the function like so:

```
void insertAtBack(string inputName, Node **head) 
{
    Node *tail = *head;
    while(tail->next != NULL)
        tail = tail->next;
    tail->next = new Node();
    tail->next->name = inputName;
    tail->next->next = NULL;
}
```

Also don't forget to initialize `head->next = nullptr;`

> ```
> if (head == NULL) {
>                  head = new Node();
>                  head->name = testName;
>                  head->next = nullptr; <--- add
>             }
> ```

---

It is better however if `insertAtBack` is prepared to handle `head` when `head` is `NULL`. The whole reason you pass `Node **head` is because you want a reference to the pointer so you can initialize it. So you can modify the code as:

```
void insertAtBack(string inputName, Node **head) 
{
    Node *new_node = new Node();
    new_node->name = inputName;
    new_node->next = nullptr;

    if(*head)
    {
        Node *tail = *head;
        while(tail->next)
            tail = tail->next;
        tail->next = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        *head = new_node;
    }
}

void printList(Node *head) 
{
    Node *node = head;
    while(node) 
    {
        cout << node->name << endl;
        node = node->next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    cout << "This implements a linked list" << endl;
    Node *head = NULL;
    string testName;
    while(true) 
    {
        printOptions();
        int option;
        std::cin >> option;
        switch(option) 
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter student name" << endl;
            std::cin >> testName;
            insertAtBack(testName, &head);
            break;
        case 2: printList(head); break;
        case 3: exit(1); break;
        default: exit(1); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```